# Is there a way to import a text file into a list in python, and have each character a separate item within that list?

Tags: python

I have a text file containing this information:

```
Site Name: Alphabet
Password: $1xKjE&a
Site Name: Chicken Nugget
Password: 6o!XkL7sm~6296*&
Site Name: Elliot
Password: 5*2uIM#@V6E@
```

(More information is appendable, but this is what is in the file currently for testing) - The information I want to keep stored within the text file is Website Names and the Password for that site, which is randomly generated by the program I am working on. I am wanting to add a form of encryption to this to make it more secure.

However, I would like it so that I can import all this information into a list in python, in separate items within that list, so that I can create a sort of Cipher.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to store in the list ? Can you wrote down a sample of your expectated list ?

Comment: `list(open('somefile').read())`

Comment: There are python cryptography packages that work on strings. The only reason to roll your own is if you want the practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can `open()` the file and then `read()` it - this will give you the contents of the file as a string. Then you can iterate over the string to get each character.

```
with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    for c in f.read():
        # do something with c
        print(c)
```

Result:

```
S
i
t
e

N
a
m
e
:
...
```

Keep in mind you will get the newline `\n` characters while iterating - and you should process them as well.

PS: Don't try to roll your own crypto - use a library. Rolling your own crypto is only okay for learning purposes.

Comment: Well, the entire reason i'm trying to do this whole thing, is to practice my coding skills, and file handling is one of my weaker points, so i'd rather not resort to using libraries. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
with open('scratch.txt', 'r') as f:
    file_lines = f.readlines()


websites = []
passwords = []

for line in file_lines:
    line_tokens = list(line.split(': ')[1].strip())
    if 'Site Name' in line:
        websites.append(line_tokens)
    else:
        passwords.append(line_tokens)

print 'websites'
[['A', 'l', 'p', 'h', 'a', 'b', 'e', 't'], 
 ['C', 'h', 'i', 'c', 'k', 'e', 'n', ' ', 'N', 'u', 'g', 'g', 'e', 't'], 
 ['E', 'l', 'l', 'i', 'o', 't']
]


print 'passwords'
[['$', '1', 'x', 'K', 'j', 'E', '&', 'a'], 
 ['6', 'o', '!', 'X', 'k', 'L', '7', 's', 'm', '~', '6', '2', '9', '6', '*', '&'], 
 ['5', '*', '2', 'u', 'I', 'M', '#', '@', 'V', '6', 'E', '@']
]
```

We basically iterate through each line of the file and toss a password or a website into the corresponding list. You can then manipulate the chars of each nested list as you'd like. This is the basic idea, but you can build from here and adjust your code to store chars as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is large, you're probably better off reading a block at a time:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.8/bin/python3

list_ = []
with open('/etc/passwd') as file_:
    while True:
        block = file_.read(4096)
        if not block:
            break
        list_.extend(block)

print(list_)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to store site names/password pairs.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(str)  # dictionary of str -> str
with open("so_passwords_test.txt", "r") as in_file:
    lines = [e.strip() for e in in_file.readlines()]  # get each line, removing trailing white characters
    total_len = len(lines)
    i = 0
    while i < total_len - 1: # from 0 to 5, so that we stop at the last site name, and can get the password at i+1
        site_name    = lines[i].split(":", 1)[1]   # get site name, splitting on first ':', in case there's one in the site name
        password     = lines[i+1].split(":", 1)[1] # get password for this site name on 1st ':', in case there's one in the pwd
        d[site_name] = password                    # adding a key/value pair to d (site name, password)
        i += 2                                     # moving 2 positions, since 2 were used for site name + pwd

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, " -- ", v)
```

Output (printed just to show you, but the results are in a dictionary that you can iterate over or look at/search into by each key):

```
Alphabet  --   $1xKjE&a
Chicken Nugget  --   6o!XkL7sm~6296*&
Elliot  --   5*2uIM#@V6E@
```

I'm assuming site names are unique. If they're not, use a `defaultdict` of `list` instead, like this:

`d = defaultdict(list)`

And when adding a password for a site, instead of

```
d[site_name] = password
```

Do

```
d[site_name].append(password)
```

With `defaultdict`, you don't need to check if the key already exists.
Think about edge cases, such as `:` in your site names.
I'm also working on the assumption that lines in your file work in pairs, the one at the even index being a site name, and the one being at +1 of each even index being the site's password.

If things get more complicated than that, either some file cleanup beforehand, or regular expressions, might come in handy !

Good luck